# Android maps show marker only at specific zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-markers

I want to display the locations of bus stations on a google map. The problem is there are lot and when I zoom out it gets really messy. Can't i just display the markers above a specific zoom level or make them resize with the map?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not specifically what you want, but it can help you. It worked for me.

According to the tutorial created by Paul Trebilcox Ruiz in [this web](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-google-maps-for-android-advanced--cms-24789):

> When a map has a lot of data points in a small area, it can get
>   cluttered very quickly as the user zooms out. Not only this, but
>   having too many markers displayed at once can cause some devices to
>   slow down considerably.
>
> In order to help alleviate some of the frustration caused by these
>   issues, you can use the Google Maps Utils library to animate your
>   markers into clusters. The first thing you need to do is create a new
>   model object that implements the `ClusterItem` interface. This model
>   needs to implement the `getPosition` method from the `ClusterItem`
>   interface in order to return a valid `LatLng` object.

```
public class ClusterMarkerLocation implements ClusterItem 
{
     private LatLng position;

     public ClusterMarkerLocation( LatLng latLng ) 
     {
         position = latLng;
     }

     @Override
     public LatLng getPosition() 
     {
         return position;
     }

     public void setPosition( LatLng position ) {
         this.position = position;
     }
 }
```

> With the model created, you can create a new Activity called
>   `ClusterMarkerActivity` and add it to your manifest. When you initialize
>   your map, you need to create a `ClusterManager`, associate it with your
>   `GoogleMap`, and add your `LatLng` positions as `ClusterMarkerLocations` to
>   the `ClusterManager` for the utility to know what to cluster. Take a
>   look at the implementation of `initMarkers` to better understand how
>   this works.

```
private void initMarkers() 
{
     ClusterManager<ClusterMarkerLocation> clusterManager = new ClusterManager<ClusterMarkerLocation>( this, mGoogleMap);
     mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);

     double lat;
     double lng;
     Random generator = new Random();

     for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
     {
         lat = generator.nextDouble() / 3;
         lng = generator.nextDouble() / 3;

         if(generator.nextBoolean()) 
         {
             lat = -lat;
         }

         if(generator.nextBoolean()) 
         {
             lng = -lng;
         }

         clusterManager.addItem( new ClusterMarkerLocation(new LatLng( mCenterLocation.latitude + lat, mCenterLocation.longitude + lng)));
     }
 }
```

> In this sample, we create 1000 random points to display and add them
>   to the map. The Google Maps Utils library handles everything else for
>   us.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you were looking for.

- Create a global variable to store markers.

  `List<Marker> list = new ArrayList<>();`
- Add all markers to it like.

  ```
      Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(name).snippet(snippet));
      list.add(marker);
  ```
- Then set an `OnCameraChangeListener`.

  ```
      googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new 
      GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
      for(Marker m:list){
          m.setVisible(cameraPosition.zoom>8);
      //8 here is your zoom level, you can set it as your need.
      }
      }
      });
  ```

See my complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508764/8244632)

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering) to your map.

When a user zooms out, the makers are combined into cluster which makes viewing map easier. When user zooms in, markers show on the map.