# Optimized and not deprecated way for displaying markerOptions only if zoom is above a value

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I want to display the thousand markers of my map only if the zoom is higher than 15.

Searching here I found this solution, but it is deprecated and is not good if you are showing a thousand of markers, so I'm searching for a better solution more optimized:

[Google Maps Android - Only show markers below a certain zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508549/google-maps-android-only-show-markers-below-a-certain-zoom-level)

```
List<Marker> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add([a thousand of markers]);

googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        for(Marker m:list){
            m.setVisible(cameraPosition.zoom>15);
        }
    }
});
```

Is it possible to achieve this with an optimized solution?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use non-deprecated API calls, use the new [Camera Change Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#camera_change_events):

```
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {

        float zoomLevel = googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;

        for(Marker m : list){
            m.setVisible(zoomLevel > 15);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: is this the most efficient way?