# how to show markers according to zoom level of map

Tags: android, google-maps

I use lots of markers in my map and if I zoom out there are lots of big markers which block the view of other map object. What I want is to show markers only if the zoom level is small. I used this but it does not work:

```
final List<Marker> list = new ArrayList<>();

        final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(markerIcon)
                .title(title));

        list.add(marker);


        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                for(Marker m:list){

                    m.setVisible(cameraPosition.zoom>8);
                    //8 here is your zoom level, you can set it as your need.
                }


            }
        });
```

I want to show marker only when the zoom level is less than like in this photo

[image]

And disable them if the zoom is like this
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use `Marker Clustering`

[image]

Here is a summary of the steps required:

1. Implement ClusterItem to represent a marker on the map. The cluster
   item returns the position of the marker as a LatLng object, and an
   optional title or snippet.
2. Add a new ClusterManager to group the cluster items (markers) based
   on zoom level.
3. Set the map's OnCameraIdleListener() to the ClusterManager, since
   ClusterManager implements the listener.
4. If you want to add specific functionality in response to a marker
       click event, set the map's OnMarkerClickListener() to the
           ClusterManager, since ClusterManager implements the listener.
5. Feed the markers into the ClusterManager.

You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering)

Comment: if I will use marker clustering and if I zoom out it will show my markers like in screenshot above? if it like that will be better but not what I want.

Comment: I want to disable all markers if it exceeds zoom level 8

Comment: @White you can try this answer 
here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508764/4377954

Comment: I have already tried it as you can see the code in my question I take from that answer

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it actually works. But note that zoom level 8 is quite far out; I recreated the sector in your second screenshot and it actually has a zoom level of about 12.

Also note that OnCameraChangeListener is deprecated and you should use OnCameraMoveListener instead.

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraMove() {
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
        for(Marker m:list){

            m.setVisible(cameraPosition.zoom>8);
            //8 here is your zoom level, you can set it as your need.
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: in second picture I want the markers to bes disabled and if I zoom in and its zoom less than 8 it will show the markers

Comment: I will try setoncameramove listener and report about it

Comment: The zoom level will get bigger if you zoom in, so I think you mean "greater than 8"?. And as I wrote, the zoom level in the second picture is about 12, so you should check for a zoom level of 12 or 13 instead of 8. `cameraPosition.zoom>12`